# How to call customize python function for sending mail in case of failure of task in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I have written a send_email.py python script, which runs perfectly fine.

How to call this function in the send_email.py script of DAG so that above function triggers with required DAG_ID, RUN_ID, LOG_URL, TASK_ID

Can anyone help with this as my current version is 2.5.0

BELOW is the send_email.py

```
import requests
from airflow.utils.email import send_email

APITOKAN = 'abcdefghijklmnop'
SUBJECT = 'Airflow Testing Mail'
FROM = 'user@domain.com'
REPLAY_TO = 'user@domain.com'
TO = 'firstname.lastname@domain.com'
URL = 'https://email.domain-apps.com/email-service/smtp/sendmail'

def send_email(MSG):
    try:
        print('Email function start...!')
        ApiTokan = APITOKAN
        url = URL
        payload = {'subject': SUBJECT,
                   'from': FROM,
                   'replyTo': REPLAY_TO,
                   'html': MSG,
                   'to': TO
                   }
        headers = {
            "email-api-key": ApiTokan,
        }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers, verify=None)
        print(response.status_code)

        print('Email Function END')

    except Exception as ex:
        print('exception from function triggered...!')
        print(ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

define the following function and call it on_execute_callback/on_success_callback/on_failure_callback at specific task or default_args in dag for all tasks

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task


def on_trigger(context):
    message = """
            *State {state}
            *Dag*: {dag}
            *RunID* {run_id}
            *Task*: {task}
            *Execution Time*: {exec_date}
            *Log Url*: {log_url}
            """.format(
        state=context.get("task_instance").state,
        task=context.get("task_instance").task_id,
        dag=context.get("task_instance").dag_id,
        run_id=context.get("task_instance").run_id,
        exec_date=context.get("execution_date"),
        log_url=context.get("task_instance").log_url,
    )
    send_email(message)


def send_email(message):
    print(message)

def on_success_dag(context):
    print(context.get("dag_run").dag_id)

with DAG(
    dag_id="test_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args={
        "start_date": datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        "retries": 0,
        "on_execute_callback": on_trigger,
        "on_failure_callback": on_trigger,
        "on_success_callback": on_trigger,
        "catchup": False,
    },
    on_success_callback=on_success_dag,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
    tags=["test"],
) as dag:
    @task
    def print_hello():
        print("hello")

    (print_hello())
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to this airflow, can you bit elaborate in the code

Comment: @AustinJackson, updated my answer with full dag example that run on_trigger every time a task is execute. on_trigger collects the data from the task_instance creates the message and call the send_mail (in my example it only print but you can use your example here)

Comment: Thank you for the needful. But over here the task print_hello is executed, it will call automatically the on_trigger based on the state, as in case of failure it will call failure state and in case success it will call the success message? Will this be done for every task, and what about the overall dag successful completion

Comment: in this example because its on the dag default_args it will be on every execution of task. if you need on every time task fails or success add it to on_success_callback or on_failure_callback. if you need it for specific task add it to the specific task definition

Comment: dag also has those callbacks

Comment: so over here in the code instead of                                                          def send_email(message):
    print(message)                                                                                                   I can say in the start as "import send_email" for my function to be called right

Comment: right. But if you put it not under the dags folder then you will need to add it your sys.path. Start inside the dag

Comment: Oh thank you. And in case overall successful of DAG that is all task completed successful then, how to deliver with the same code?

Comment: @AustinJackson, I updated my answer with on_success_callback in the dag level

Comment: I have no words for your help. Thank you a ton, it made my day. Will definitely do hard work and learn rest of the stuff. And would get connected in case anything required in future.

Comment: With pleasure. Feel free to contact anytime. Please also vote this answer for others to use it. 10x